# Unable to update state hook on keyDown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update a state on SpaceBar press,
but it seems that the state value is not changing (always printing 0)

Here is what I tried :

```js
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const keyHandler = () => {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 32:
                setCounter(counter + 1);
                console.log(counter)
                break;
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", e => keyHandler(e));
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div className="App">
            {counter}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

## UPDATE:

for future you, read about closures in react and how to deal with them 
i found this article (along with the accepted answer here) very useful:
https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

Comment: I believe you may be missing an `e` in your keyhandler parameter list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `keyHandler` callback closes over your state value and thus does not react to updates. See [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```js
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  const keyHandler = (e) => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 32:
        setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
        break;
      default:
      // do nothing
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyHandler);

    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyHandler);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button>click me</button>
      {counter}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document. getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so so much!!! it seems to be working but can you please give more explanation, I read the link you provided but I still don't understand how it works

Comment: It's not a trivial topic and there are many articles about it. I would kindly ask you to refer to those. The short version is that when `keyHandler` is created it keeps a reference to its surrounding state. At that point `counter` is `0`. When you call it for the first time your app seems to work just fine. But as long as `keyHandler` exists in memory, it will always think `counter` is `0`.